# MySQL: How can I INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN results

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have a table `items` which is the points on the map. They have list of the nearest subway stations in table `item_stations` (`item_id`, `station_id`). The names these stations are placed in table `stations` (`id`, `station_name`, `station_direction`, ...).

So I need to return in SQL-query item-data with the names of the nearest stations.

```
SELECT 
    i.id, i.title, i.description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.station_id) as stations_ids,
FROM items i
    LEFT JOIN item_stations s ON s.item_id = s.id
WHERE id = ?
GROUP BY i.id
LIMIT 1
```

How I must write `INNER JOIN` WITH table `stations` ON `stations.id = s.station_id`?

Comment: how do you know if it is the nearest station?

Comment: @JW웃 this logic is in other algorithm, before adding to `item_stations` table. So I only need to join rows from this table to result (with getting station names from table `stations`).

Comment: Your query contain non-aggregated fields in the `SELECT` which are not included in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL allows this, but it's non-standard and confusing syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want something like this?

```
SELECT 
    i.id, i.title, i.description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.station_id) as stations_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(stations.station_name) as stations_names
FROM 
    items i
LEFT JOIN 
    item_stations s ON s.item_id = s.id
INNER JOIN stations on
    stations.id = s.station_id
WHERE i.id = ?
GROUP BY i.id, i.title, i.description
LIMIT 1
```

I placed **i**.id in WHERE block, cause **id** field is in the 2 tables - item_stations and items. Mb that was a problem?

Comment: There is no point in `INNER JOIN`ing a `LEFT JOIN`... you can just use all `INNER JOIN`s at this point.

Comment: Yes. I've just edited comment to mention it, but then suddenly saw @Matthew 's comment.